# Wrong name of sectional division in appendix with cleveref

Tags: appendices, cleveref

Using the `memoir` class and the `cleveref` package as in the MWE included below, I would like to have as name of a sectional division marked with `\section` after the `\appendix` declaration, the same name as before: "section". Nonetheless, what I get is "appendix". Any hints as to how to obtain the desired behavior will be welcome.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{cleveref} 

\begin{document}
\chapter{First Chap.}\label{firstch}
This is some intro with a reference to \cref{firstch}.
\section{First Chap. Section}\label{firstchapsec}
And now a reference to \cref{firstchapsec}. This is fine; I want the name "section".
\appendix  
\chapter{First App.}\label{firstapp}
This is the app. with a reference to \cref{firstapp}.
\section{First App. Section}\label{firstappsec}
And now a reference to \cref{firstappsec}. I want to have "section" instead of "appendix".
\end{document}
```

Comment: As this also happens with the standard `book` class, this is not `memoir` related.

Comment: Good to know. Just in case that someone comes up with a `memoir`-specific answer, I'll leave the tags and the title as they are. If the answer is `memoir`-independent I'll delete the memoir tag and rephrase the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change from `appendix A.1` to `section A.1` you can use the following line in the preamble of your document:

```
\crefname{subappendix}{section}{sections}
```

Analogously, you can also change `appendix A` to `chapter A` and `appendix A.1.1` to `subsection A.1.1` with the following lines:

```
\crefname{appendix}{chapter}{chapters}
\crefname{subsubappendix}{subsection}{subsections}
```